# Show mid screen on action executing and then final screen on action executed without using AJAX in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form in a view, on click of submit button I want to execute an action method, since this action method takes a lot of time, so in meantime I want to show a mid screen(view) with some custom data, after successful execution of that action method, I want to show final view.

I can not use AJAX due to some reasons. So is there any way through which I can perform this task?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript (pretty much whatever happens dynamically in your browser) is single thread unless you are using AJAX, which you stated you do not want to do. So that means you can take a "round trip" back to the server side (in which case it would not be a pop-up on the client side or "mid screen (view)" as you call it), or use AJAX.

Comment: Is there any way out with action filters?

Comment: Action Filters and Filters in general, are on the server side. As in "before the action occurs" or "after the action has occured". If you return something to the client, you are done. There is no "half response". Either the response is returned or it's not.